# computing the following sum with few calculations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Let $p\in(0,1)$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Is there a trick that computes the sum $$\sum_{k=0}^n k {n \choose k }p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$
without much work and all? I think it is equal to $n\cdot p$.

Comment: I don't know if it might help but with the binomial theorem $$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a^k·b^{n-k}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The summation can be recognized as the expectation of a random variable $X$ having  binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$.

This random variable can be written as:$$X=B_1+\cdots+B_n$$where the $B_i$ have Bernoulli-distribution with parameter $p$.

Then with linearity of expectation we find:$$\mathbb EX=\mathbb EB_1+\cdots+\mathbb EB_n=p+\cdots+p=np$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Use
$$
k\binom{n}{k}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}.
$$ 
$$np\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1}p^{k-1}(1-p)^{n-k}=?
$$

Or by differentiating the expression
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a^kb^{n-k}=(a+b)^n
$$ with respect to $a$, derive
$$
\sum_{k=0}^nk\binom{n}{k}a^{k-1}b^{n-k}=n(a+b)^{n-1}.
$$ Let $a=p$ and $b=1-p$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}k{n \choose k }p^{k}\pars{1 - p}^{n - k}} =
\pars{1 - p}^{n}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k }k\pars{p \over 1 - p}^{k}
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.\pars{1 - p}^{n}\,\,\alpha\,\partiald{}{\alpha}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k }\alpha^{k}\,\right\vert_{\ \alpha\ =\ p/\pars{1 - p}} =
\left.\pars{1 - p}^{n - 1}\,p\,\partiald{\pars{1 + \alpha}^{n}}{\alpha}
\,\right\vert_{\ \alpha\ =\ p/\pars{1 - p}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{1 - p}^{n - 1}\,p\bracks{n\pars{1 + \alpha}^{n - 1}}
_{\ \alpha\ =\ p/\pars{1 - p}} =
\pars{1 - p}^{n - 1}\,pn\pars{1 + {p \over 1 - p}}^{n - 1} = \bbx{np}
\end{align}